# iOS UILabel on new View Controller not updating when using segue

Tags: ios, uilabel, viewcontroller, segue

I have a `UILabel(descriptionOfProgram)` on a second `ViewController(GraphViewController)` that needs to be set when the segue from the original MVC occurs.

Currently, in my main MVC, I do two things in my `prepareForSegue:`:

1. I set an `@property NSString` in GraphVewController to the string I want it to be.
2. I set descriptionOfProgram's text to be equal to that string by calling a function in `GraphViewController setDescriptionLabel:`.

When `graphViewController` comes on string, the text is not in the label. During testing, I created a button called `test` in `GraphViewController` to call `setDescriptionLabel` when pressed. This worked. Any ideas on what's going on?

I included `GraphViewController.h` and `.m` in the second MVC, and `GraphingCalculatorViewController.m` in the Main MVC.

GraphViewController.h:

```
//
//  GraphViewController.h
//  GraphingCalculator
//
//  Created by Graham Gaylor on 3/1/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSArray *program;
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString *description;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionOfProgram;
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender;
- (void)setDescriptionLabel:(NSString *)description;

@end
```

GraphViewController.m:

```
//
//  GraphViewController.m
//  GraphingCalculator
//
//  Created by Graham Gaylor on 3/1/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GraphViewController.h"
#import "GraphView.h"


@interface GraphViewController() <GraphViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GraphView *graphView;

@end

@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize program = _program;
@synthesize descriptionOfProgram = _descriptionOfProgram;
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize graphView = _graphView;

- (void)setProgram:(NSArray *)program
{
    _program = program;
    [self.graphView setNeedsDisplay]; // any time our Model changes, redraw our View
    self.graphView.dataSource = self; // setting graphView delegate GraphVC

}

- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    self.descriptionOfProgram.text = @"test";
    [self setDescriptionLabel:self.description];
}

- (void)setDescriptionLabel:(NSString *)description
{
    NSLog(@"Got into setDescriptionLabel");
    self.descriptionOfProgram.text =  @"hello";
}

- (NSArray *)programForGraphView:(GraphView *)sender {
    return self.program;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setDescriptionOfProgram:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

This is my main MVC. I got rid of all the extra functions that don't deal with the seque.

GraphingCalculatorViewController.m:

```
//
//  GraphingCalculatorViewController.m
//  GraphingCalculator
//
//  Created by Graham Gaylor on 3/1/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GraphingCalculatorViewController.h"
#import "GraphViewController.h"


@interface GraphingCalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *programToGraph;
@end

@implementation GraphingCalculatorViewController

@synthesize programToGraph = _programToGraph;

- (void)setAndShowGraph:(NSArray *)program {
    self.programToGraph = program;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowGraph" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"setAndShowGraph");
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowGraph"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setProgram:self.programToGraph]; // sets GraphVC's program to current program
        [segue.destinationViewController setDescriptionLabel:[CalculatorBrain descriptionOfProgram:self.programToGraph]];
        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue");
    }
}
- (IBAction)graphPressed {
    [self setAndShowGraph:self.brain.program];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setVariablesUsed:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue:` is called before `viewDidLoad:` so your IBOutlet will be nil. Try setting the incoming value to a `NSString` and then use that string to populate the label on `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: Thanks! I'm watching the Standford Lecture series and I haven't gotten to the viewDidLoad function yet :-/

Much appreciated.